# Multiple Shortcut Icons?

Tags: html, favicon

I saw this today and was wondering how it can be achieved? I am searching for another example but in the meantime will drop the question here too.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The page's `<title>` start with the [Unicode emoji symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) for [Briefcase, `U+1F4BC`:](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4bc/index.htm)

[image]

Confirmed by setting the title on this page:

[image]

Comment: cool - thats what I thought, but someone deserves points for being the only answer on Stackoverflow.